# Cannot use poly(x) within a loop? 'degree' must be less than number of unique points

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

```
library(ISLR)
```

Choosing a model based on any feature:

```
amodel <- lm(crim ~ poly(dat$zn, 3), data = Boston)
```

Works, returns a model. When I try to do this with every variable in a loop I get:

```
dat <- dplyr::select(Boston, -crim)
sapply(dat, function(x) {
  mod <- lm(crim ~ poly(x, 3), data = Boston)
  summary(mod)
})
```

> Error in poly(x, 3) : 'degree' must be less than number of unique
>   points

How can I get this to run within a loop? I would like to create a model for each `poly(feature, 3)` in Boston (minus crim feature).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Numerical overflow** would be my guess. If you dig into the code for `poly`, you'll see that it generates the individual polynomial terms as an intermediate step:

`X <- outer(x, seq_len(n) - 1, "^")`

and when `n` (the degree of the polynomial you want) is 3, combined with the code used to generate the linear model `lm()`, the resulting terms go up to exponentially.

Comment: So why does it work outside of a loop but not within one? The block for "amodel" above does run, just not within a loop

Comment: @DougFir, it does not work for the `chas` column no matter within or out of the for loop. That's why you get the error.

Comment: d'oh! Thanks for spotting that